# Using compound assignment pipe operator with CrossTable output for example

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, crosstab, assignment-operator

I would like to make use of the compound assignment pipe operator `%<>%`. For example using the code below I can generate a simple data frame with the required proportions:

```
data("mtcars")
Vectorize(require)(package = c("magrittr", "gmodels"),
                   character.only = TRUE)

mtcars_sum <- CrossTable(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl)$prop.row
```

as illustrated:

```
> head(mtcars_sum)
   y
x           4         6         8
  0 0.1578947 0.2105263 0.6315789
  1 0.6153846 0.2307692 0.1538462
```

I would like to undertake the same transformation but using the `%<>` pipe:

```
mtcars_sum %<>%
  CrossTable(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl)$prop.row
```

this returns the following error:

```
> mtcars_sum %<>%
+   CrossTable(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl)$prop.row
Error in .$CrossTable(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl) : 
  3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `%<>%` operator works only when `mtcars_sum` already exists.  It is equivalent to `mtcars_sum <- mtcars_sum %>% CrossTable(...)`.  Since your `$` call has all the arguments specified and the pipe is also trying to assign `mtcars_sum` into an argument, you have one more argument than `$` can accept.

Comment: Thank you for the useful explanation!